# Calculate total recyclerview item height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I tried following method but it's only count visible item height any way to calculate total height of item, I want to calculate total height of recyclerview item and set it to the viewpager2 height any way to achieve this, recyclerview is in different fragment and it's connect with viewPager2 private fun getTotalHeightOfRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView): Int {
val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager
var totalHeight = 0

```
    if (layoutManager != null && recyclerView.adapter != null) {
        for (i in 0 until recyclerView.adapter!!.itemCount) {
            val view = layoutManager.getChildAt(i)
            view?.let {
                val params = view.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
                totalHeight += view.height + params.topMargin + params.bottomMargin
                Log.d("loop",totalHeight.toString())
            }
        }
    }
    return totalHeight
}
```

Comment: A `RecyclerView` is only needed if some items may not be visible. If you know that all items will always be visible, do not use `RecyclerView`. Use `ConstrantLayout` or `LinearLayout`.

Comment: instead of using adapter.itemcount use the size of your list that you pass in the recycler view to display

Comment: @zaidkhan I tried not working loop continuously run and 5 item visible in screen show only count 5 item view height

Comment: Why do you need it in first place?